# Excel formula hyperlink not working in GERMAN locale

Tags: excel, hyperlink, formula

I have a spreadsheet with a formula similar to the following:
**=HYPERLINK("https://example.com/issue?id=MS-212", "MS-212")**

The hyperlink is displayed and works when used in with the default US locale.  When the locale is changed to german, the formula fails with a "We found a problem with this formula. Try clicking Insert Function on the Formulas tab to fix it, or click Help for more info on common formula problems." message.

Any solutions to make this work with non-US locale?

Comment: Shouldn't you be using a `;` instead of a `,` for the DE-DE locale? e.g. `=HYPERLINK("https://example.com/issue?id=MS-212"; "MS-212")`. See [HYPERLINK (Funktion)](https://support.office.com/de-de/article/HYPERLINK-Funktion-333c7ce6-c5ae-4164-9c47-7de9b76f577f?ui=de-DE&rs=de-DE&ad=DE).

Comment: How did you change the locale? The `,` to `;` conversion should happen by auto-magic when Excel opens the spreadsheet.

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/668440/how-to-make-excel-formula-work-in-all-regions

Answer (score 1):

The first comment answers the question.  In a DE-DE locale, the formula should use a ';' separator instead of the ',' separator.

This requires understanding the target locale a requirement when generating a CSV for excel.